# Terrain turns white when zooming closer in unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, terrain

Got a strange problem with unity3d which turns my terrain whiter the closer i get to it. I have tried creating new projects with plain terrain and it is still the same.

See screenshots below. The closer i get the whiter the terrain turns.

[image: Zoomed out]

[image: Zooming in]

[image: Zooming in]

Comment: Restart your machine, update video drivers, generally make sure your computer is in fine working order. Also if you have a low-end video card some features of Unity may not work properly. In that case contact Unity tech support to determine whether your system specs are sufficient.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is most likely a video card/driver/capabilities issue.

Comment: Maybe looking from perspective instead iso will work have you tried that?

Comment: I don't think it's a perspective issue. I've seen this particular type too many times before (in games in general, not specifically Unity). It's typically an issue with video card/drivers, or simply not enough texture memory on the video card. Perhaps reducing screen resolution in Windows may help, also detaching any external (secondary) monitors.

Comment: I have now tried updating drivers to the beta driver from ATI, disconnect second display and rebooting with one display, changing resolution, testing with another monitor and nothing works. I have never seen anything like this occur in either 3ds or anything, only unity. I am running with Radeon 6990 so it should not be the graphics card is too weak. :/

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to decrease the base map distance for the terrain.